# First time input doesn't get submitted in React

Tags: reactjs

I'd like make an API call, which user input makes part of the API URL. Data is only fetched on demand after user submit.

My problem is: after first time input and submit, input is processed as an empty string, constructed wrong URL and made API call. (still loads data but the wrong data)

Only after second submit does it get actual user input, construct the correct URL and display the right data.

monitering network:
[image]

User input is stored in enteredWallet, `Console.log(enteredWallet)` prints the input, but `setOwner(enteredWallet)` doesn't change owner to be `enteredWallet`.

```
import { useState } from "react";

// example input:  0x147412d494731cbb91dbb5d7019464a536de04dc

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [enteredWallet, setEnteredWallet] = useState("");
  const [owner, setOwner] = useState("");

  const walletChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredWallet(event.target.value);
  };

  const submittedHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOwner(enteredWallet);
    fetchNFTHandler();
    console.log("enteredWallet:", enteredWallet);
    console.log("owner:", owner);

  };

  function fetchNFTHandler() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner=${owner}&order_direction=desc&offset=0&limit=10`
    )
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const transformedData = data.assets.map((element, index) => {
          return {
            title: element.name,
            id: index,
          };
        });
        setData(transformedData);
        console.log("fetched");
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h3>Show me assets in this wallet</h3>
        <form onSubmit={submittedHandler}>
          <input
            placeholder="wallet address"
            value={enteredWallet}
            onChange={walletChangeHandler}
          />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div>
          {data.map((element) => (
            <li key={element.id}>{element.title}</li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because owner in fetchNFTHandler doesn't update immediately after call setOwner.
Why don't use onwer as a param.

```
const submittedHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOwner(enteredWallet);
    fetchNFTHandler(enteredWallet);  //here
    console.log("enteredWallet:", enteredWallet);
    console.log("owner:", owner);
};

function fetchNFTHandler(owner) {
    fetch(
  `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner=${owner}&order_direction=desc&offset=0&limit=10`
)...
```

or if you need use it as state indeed.
use useEffect to call fetchNFTHandler

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchNFTHandler();
}, [owner]) // when owner change, fetchNFTHandler will be call
```

If you want use a variable, it can take effect at once. you can try useRef.

```
const ownerRef = useRef("");

const submittedHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ownerRef.current = enteredWallet;
    fetchNFTHandler();
};

function fetchNFTHandler(owner) {
    fetch(
  `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner=${ownerRef.current}&order_direction=desc&offset=0&limit=10`
)...
```

Comment: thanks!  why doesn't owner in fetchNFTHandler update immediately after call setOwner? is it because network delay? if so, why doesn't the program wait for owner is updated until it proceed?

Comment: it has nothing to do with network delay, when use useState，owner will update when next time render. because it is not synchronous.

Comment: Got it! so when first time calling setState of owner, it always uses the initial state, which i set as ""in this case. Other than using useEffect, is there another way to bypass the first time?

Comment: You can try useRef, it is other way, added it above

Comment: haha thanks! i haven't learnt useRef yet. was just trying to use the most primitive JS methods in react to grab the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The function returned by `useState` (in your case, `setEnteredWallet` or `setOwner`) is not synchronous. The state is not immediately changed after calling either it. If you want to call `fetchNFTHandler` every time `enteredWallet` changes, you can use `useEffect`. Or simply, you can pass `enteredWallet` to `fetchNFTHandler` as a parameter. An example usage of `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchNFTHandler();
    console.log("enteredWallet:", enteredWallet);
    console.log("owner:", owner);
}, [owner, enteredWallet]) // Call method above when owner or enteredWallet change

const submittedHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOwner(enteredWallet);
    // You don't need the following lines anymore
    // fetchNFTHandler();
    // console.log("enteredWallet:", enteredWallet);
    // console.log("owner:", owner);

};
```